# how can i inject IContentManager in Timer callback (Orchard CMS)

Tags: timer, orchardcms

```
public Models.ManagedUsersPart GetManagedUsers(int ManagedUsersId)
    {

        return _cacheManager.Get(ManagedUsersId, ctx =>
        {
            MonitorManagedUserSignal(ctx, ManagedUsersId);
            Timer = new Timer(t => DoUpdate(_contentManager,ManagedUsersId), "c", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
            var managedusers = _contentManager.Get<ManagedUsersPart>(ManagedUsersId);
            return managedusers;
        });
    }
```

and this is my DoUpdate function:

```
public void DoUpdate(IContentManager contentmanager,int ManagedUsersId)
        {
            var transation = _iworkcontext.CreateWorkContextScope().Resolve<ITransactionManager>();
            transation.RequireNew();
            var manager = getmanager();
            var modifiemanageruser = manager.Get<ManagedUsersPart>(ManagedUsersId);
            var modi = GetManagedUsers(ManagedUsersId);
            modifiemanageruser.InvitedCount = modi.InvitedCount;
}
```

and ,this is my getmanager function:

```
public IContentManager getmanager()
        {
            if (Timermanager == null)
            {
                Timermanager = _iworkcontext.CreateWorkContextScope().Resolve<IContentManager>();
            }
            return Timermanager;
        }
```

The question is "modifiemanageruser.InvitedCount = modi.InvitedCount"
this code does not persist update to database,anyone can help?

Comment: Why not just use the variable `contentmanager` that you pass in `DoUpdate`?

Comment: variable contentmanager can not be resloved,if use variable contentmanager in DoUpdate() function。